# How to save text file after use cat -n command

Tags: command-line, cat

I am created file use "cat > sample.txt". after i used "cat -b sample.txt". how to save it. ctrl+x or F2 is not working.[cat -b command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t0f5g.png)

Comment: What do you mean "save it"? Do you want the line numbers to go into the actual file? If yes, why?

Comment: yes. i want to know to my knowledge.

Comment: Beware that `cat -b sample.txt > sample.txt` will not work. In fact it will destroy the file. That's because bash will process the redirection **first** (truncating the file to zero bytes) before launching the cat command.

Comment: You can `cat -b sample.txt > tempfile && mv tempfile sample.txt`

Comment: Or install the `moreutils` package and `cat -b sample.txt | sponge sample.txt`

Comment: This command is working correctly. Thank you. cat -b sample.txt > tempfile && mv tempfile sample.txt